# Positioning shapes to website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have made a red svg shape which looks like that:

[image]

I need to use these shapes in a design which looks like this:

[image]

I've embedded this svg file in img tag and tried to position it with absolute/relative positioning and ended up with that:

[image]

It looks perfect but when I resize my browser, this happens:

[image]

I'm new to HTML/CSS and obviously don't know what I'm doing. Maybe this is the wrong way to approach it...

So here's my HTML:

```
<section id="whatwedo">
        <div class="hat"><img src="img/hat.svg" alt="Startup" style="img-responsive;"></div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1 class="text-center">what we do</h1>
                    <p class="text-center">We offer a wide range of software development and design options from a simple web development to more complicated information systems. We ensure our customers get the right thing, done the right way.</p>
                </div>
                <!--end col-md-8 col-md-offset-2-->
            </div>
            <!--end row-->


            <div class="row fields">
                <div class="col-sm-4 development-field">
                    <img src="img/development.svg" alt="Development" style="width:90px;height:90px;" class="img-responsive center-block">
                    <h2 class="text-center">develop</h2>
                    <p class="small text-center">We take pride in our experience in developing Java and PHP applications with different technologies and frameworks.</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link center-block blue" role="link" type="submit" name="op" value="Link 2">more</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 design-field">
                    <img src="img/design.png" alt="Design" style="width:90px;height:90px;" class="img-responsive center-block">
                    <h2 class="text-center">design</h2>
                    <p class="small text-center">Beauty. Simplicity. Delight. We create beautiful user experiences to solve our customers’ business problems.</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link center-block blue" role="link" type="submit" name="op" value="Link 2">more</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 startup-field">
                    <img src="img/startup.svg" alt="Startup" style="width:90px;height:90px;" class="img-responsive center-block">
                    <h2 class="text-center">startup</h2>
                    <p class="small text-center">We love being a part of new innovation and help your startup succeed by developing the technology you need to push forward.</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link center-block blue" role="link" type="submit" name="op" value="Link 2">more</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--end row fields-->
        </div>
        <!--end container-->

    </section>
    <!--end whatwedo-->
```

And here's the CSS:

```
/*what we do*/

.fields {
    margin-top: 64px;
}

.development-field img,
.design-field img,
.startup-field img {
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}

#aboutprocess {
    margin-top: 64px;
    padding: 64px 0;
    background: url(../img/tech_bg.jpg) repeat center center fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 344px;
    background-size: contain;
}

#aboutprocess p {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.hat {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -110px;
}

#whatwedo {
    position: relative;
}
```

I hope you guys can help me out. I've been working on this for 3 hours already and I feel like I'm gonna go crazy soon. Here's a [link](http://dolm.ragne.me/) to a demo page as well. Thank you.

Comment: first look : maybe you mistaping style="img-responsive;" , style can't be a class, try class="img-responsive" in         <div class="hat"><img src="img/hat.svg" alt="Startup" style="img-responsive;"></div>

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I corrected that. Thank you for pointing that out. :) @Bandi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/leonardoaraujocosta/ubdou9oa/3/), based on what you said. I made a small change in the HTML and CSS structure.

I have helped you in any way

```css
#home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(14, 124, 132, 0.8), rgba(14, 124, 132, 0.8)), url("http://dolm.ragne.me/img/landing_bg.jpg") no-repeat 0 0 fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.hat {
 width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
 background: url("http://dolm.ragne.me/img/hat.svg") no-repeat center bottom;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section id="home">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>Heading sample</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis repudiandae illum ipsum voluptatibus eos magni est rem, quae recusandae. Sequi, quae voluptatum alias adipisci, quas repudiandae eveniet et quis placeat.</p>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="hat"></div>
</section>

<section id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>Heading sample</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis repudiandae illum ipsum voluptatibus eos magni est rem, quae recusandae. Sequi, quae voluptatum alias adipisci, quas repudiandae eveniet et quis placeat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis repudiandae illum ipsum voluptatibus eos magni est rem, quae recusandae. Sequi, quae voluptatum alias adipisci, quas repudiandae eveniet et quis placeat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis repudiandae illum ipsum voluptatibus eos magni est rem, quae recusandae. Sequi, quae voluptatum alias adipisci, quas repudiandae eveniet et quis placeat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis repudiandae illum ipsum voluptatibus eos magni est rem, quae recusandae. Sequi, quae voluptatum alias adipisci, quas repudiandae eveniet et quis placeat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis repudiandae illum ipsum voluptatibus eos magni est rem, quae recusandae. Sequi, quae voluptatum alias adipisci, quas repudiandae eveniet et quis placeat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis repudiandae illum ipsum voluptatibus eos magni est rem, quae recusandae. Sequi, quae voluptatum alias adipisci, quas repudiandae eveniet et quis placeat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis repudiandae illum ipsum voluptatibus eos magni est rem, quae recusandae. Sequi, quae voluptatum alias adipisci, quas repudiandae eveniet et quis placeat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis repudiandae illum ipsum voluptatibus eos magni est rem, quae recusandae. Sequi, quae voluptatum alias adipisci, quas repudiandae eveniet et quis placeat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis repudiandae illum ipsum voluptatibus eos magni est rem, quae recusandae. Sequi, quae voluptatum alias adipisci, quas repudiandae eveniet et quis placeat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis repudiandae illum ipsum voluptatibus eos magni est rem, quae recusandae. Sequi, quae voluptatum alias adipisci, quas repudiandae eveniet et quis placeat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If my answer helps you, please click in "Accept response" ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. :) So I had put the svg div into the wrong section and the "position: bottom" is something that holds this svg in place (bottom of the section) while resizing the window. I learned a lot from you, I really appreciate it. @Leonardo Costa

Comment: @bijoume You're welcome! Glad to know I could help you!